# Is there a variable type which can refer to a control (type may differ) in vb6?

Tags: vb6, controls

I have two controls which both serve the same function with different data sources (Access vs SQL) in a legacy vb6 application. I am trying to create a variable which refers to the control which is applicable to that data source (In this case, an ssOleDBCombo vs an SSDBCombo). Is this possible in vb6, or will I just need to do something along the lines of the following:

```
IF SQL Then
    ssOLEDBCombo
Else
    ssdbcombo
End if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "Object" Datatype worked. I needed to set it equal to the control using a Set statement

```
SET mCombo = ssOLEDBCombo
```

I am more familiar with vb.net/c# where this Set keyword isnt necessary.

Comment: You could use the Control data type. Dim mCombo As Control

Answer (score 1):

VB has two statements `Let` and `Set`. Set was introduced to Basic when objects became available.

As basic can tell by context when you are assigning a data to a variable, `Let` is optional. However `Set` isn't.

```
Let x = 5
```

is the same as

```
x =5
```

But an object (always COM - VB has a quick, private, internal COM implmentation, but usually defaults to normal COM) requires `SET`.